# Upload to S3 bucket through API Gateway AWS Service Proxy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway

As in the title, I can't seem to get it to work, i'm following the high level guide detailed [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integrating-api-with-aws-services-s3.html) but any images uploaded seem to be blank.

What i've set up:

```
/images/{object} - PUT
 > Integration Request
   AWS Region: ap-southeast-2
   AWS Service: S3
   AWS Subdomain [bucket name here]
   HTTP method: PUT
   Path override: /{object}
   Execution Role [I have one set up]
 > URL Path Paramaters
   object -> method.request.path.object
```

I'm trying to use Postman to send a PUT request with Content-Type: image/png and the body is a binary upload of a png file.

I've also tried using curl:

```
curl -X PUT -H "Authorization: Bearer [token]" -H "Content-Type: image/gif" --upload-file ~/Pictures/bart.gif https://[api-url]/dev/images/cool.gif
```

It creates the file on the server and the size seems to be double what ever was uploaded, when viewed I just get "image has an error".

When I try with .txt files (content-type: text/plain) it seems to work though.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does the object actually created in S3 also have the correct Content-Type, as shown in the console?  Does the ETag in S3 match the md5 hash of the original file?

Comment: Content type seems to be the same, an md5 does not match the ETag... interesting

Comment: Also the local file md5 does not match the md5 of the uploaded file (if I download it again), just tried .txt files and they seem to work :|

Comment: Updated original question with this extra info :)

Answer (score 2):

After reading **alot** and chatting to AWS technical support, the problem seems to be that you can't do binary uploads through API Gateway as anything that passes through automatically goes through a UTF-8 encode.

There are a few workarounds for this I can think of, my solution will be to base64 the files before upload and trigger a lambda when they hit the bucket to decode them

Comment: I'm not sure if this applies to your situation, but at the bottom of this document: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integrating-api-with-aws-services-s3.html
...there's a note: "To upload or download an image, you need to set content handling to CONVERT_TO_BINARY."

Answer (score 1):

This is a old post, but I got a solution. 
AWS now support binary upload through APIGateway [READ](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-payload-encodings-configure-with-console.html).

In general, go to your API settings, and add a Binary Media type.

After that, you can handle the file in base64